# Why can't a non toxic shower hose be used as a length of pipe in say a bathroom?

Tags: plumbing, shower, hose

I've come across a shower hose that's been used to connect a water supply to a tap.

Comment: Because if you're going to bury it behind drywall, it needs to be more reliable than a shower hose.  Code is there to protect you and save you money by reducing damage, and to protect the next owner of the house from shoddy work.

Comment: Is it a "shower hose" or flexible tubing?  Shower hoses might be made to a less quality(usually out in the open) than proper plumbing.

Comment: It can be used, but only after shutoff valve.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica appreciate your answer,  there are many different shower hoses on market, a great deal compliant with water regs . My question was because I never thought about it before, briaded hoses kink and burst, and a decent shower hose wouldn't so my thoughts were for the exact reg reason..

Answer (score 2):

Flexi shower hose - between mixer and shower head normally - is not designed to take much pressure. It doesn't need to. Whenever the mixer tap (or whatever feeds it) is on, the water flows straight out through it and then through the shower head. So the non-toxicality is not the main consideration.

Comment: Hi there.thanks for answering . Yep appreciated,  however,  most hoses in UK are guaranteed to 3.5bar of pressure.  This is the usual allowance of pressurised systems in UK.

Comment: Once again, location info. would be a useful piece of info. to tell everyone! In UK, I used such a hose, for a similar, but temporary purose, and it didn't do the job for long before it broke. Hence my warning.

Answer (score 0):

Because the hoses can be only used after easy accessible Shut -off vale, and not as permanent connection without a valve.